# How to print one single line into a text file

Tags: java

I want to print out a single line to count how many line have been written into the text file, for example:

```
202.32.92.47 | 271 | 200
ix-or7-27.ix.netcom.com | 205908 | 200
ram0.huji.ac.il | 271 | 200
eagle40.sasknet.sk.ca | 1116 | 200
eagle40.sasknet.sk.ca | 49649 | 200
cdc8g5.cdc.polimi.it | 461 | 200
Total number of line: 6
```

Here's part of my code:

```
            Pattern string1 = Pattern.compile("usask.ca");
            Pattern string2 = Pattern.compile("128.233.");
            Pattern string3 = Pattern.compile("200");
            Matcher matcher1 = string1.matcher(sourceAddress);
            Matcher matcher2 = string2.matcher(sourceAddress);
            Matcher matcher3 = string3.matcher(responseCode);
            for (int i = 0; i < sourceAddress.length(); i++)
                if ((!matcher1.find() || !matcher2.find()) && matcher3.find()) {
                bw.write(sourceAddress + " | " + replySizeInBytes + " | " + responseCode);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write("Total number of line: " + i);
                bw.newLine();
            }
```

but the above code is not actually doing the count, it just stay at 1 and keep printing out after each address. I am not sure what I've done wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Scanner` and calling `nextLine()`, along with `File`. [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) the link. This was really quick something like this would print out the number of lines:

```
public void printLineCount() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File f = new File("filename.txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    int i = 0;
    while(s.hasNextLine()) {
        i++;
        s.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of line: " + i);
}
```

If you need to keep your code, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example:

```
File file = new File("C:");
    try{
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
        output.println("ping www.google.cm");
        output.close();
    }catch(IOException ex){
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setAutoRequestFocus(true);
    }
```